# スマホアプリのFaceBooKログインでサーバーサイドのアクセストークンチェックでエラーになります。

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook-api

＜内容＞
現在cordovaを使用したスマートフォンアプリを開発しています。

アプリ側でFBログインして取得したアクセストークンをサーバー側に送信し、
サーバーサイドで、再度トークンが正しいかFB認証してログインしたいのですが、
サーバーサイドで送られてきたトークンをチェックする際に下記のエラーが発生し、
解決できません。

「You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app」

※FB管理者で登録している端末ではエラーにはなりません。一般ユーザーからのアクセスでエラーとなります。
 アクセストークン、ユーザーID等の必要なパラメーターは取得できています。

＜補足＞
開発言語
  クライアントサイド
  ・react.js

サーバーサイド
  ・ruby on rails

使用している端末
  ・iPhone（IOS9）

使用しているAPI
  クライアントサイド・・・アクセストークン取得
  ・cordova-plugin-facebook4

サーバーサイド・・・アクセストークンのチェック
  ・koala（Graph API）

使用しているサーバー
  ・AWS

FBで使用しているPermissions（申請完了）
  ・email
  ・public_profile
  ・user_friends
  ・user_birthday
  ・user_work_history

ーーーーーー
エラー箇所のソース(rails)

> def verify_facebook_token!
>       @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:facebook_token])
>       # https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token? に問い合わせ
>       token_info = @graph.debug_token(params[:facebook_token])　←ここでエラー
>
> ```
> # 期限切れなどになっていないかを確認
> raise ArgumentError unless token_info['data']['is_valid']
>
> # Facebook の user_id も確認する
> raise ArgumentError unless token_info['data']['user_id'].eql?(params[:facebook_id])
>
> # app_id は最初にアプリを登録したときにわかっているので固定値
> raise ArgumentError unless token_info['data']['app_id'].eql?(ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'])   rescue
> logger.info("is_valid: #{@graph.debug_token(params[:facebook_token])}")
> render template: 'api/v1/errors/facebook_token', status: 400   end
> ```

ーーーーーー
エラーログ

Koala::Facebook::ClientError (type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) You must provide an app access token or a user access token that is an owner or developer of the app, x-fb-trace-id: GjfLrs52rVy [HTTP 400]):
    app/controllers/api/auth_controller.rb:34:in `rescue in verify_facebook_token!'

    app/controllers/api/auth_controller.rb:28:in`verify_facebook_token!'

Answer (score 1):

> @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:facebook_token])

この時に渡した params[:facebook_token] にユーザトークンが入ってしまっていないでしょうか？

少しややこしいのですが、まず /debug_token はユーザトークンではアクセスできない仕様となっています。

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/debug_token/
>   Permissions: An app access token or an app developer's user access token for the app associated with the input_token is required to access this endpoint.

かわりに、アプリトークンか開発者のユーザトークンを利用する必要があります。 (FB管理者で登録されている端末でエラーにならないのは、このためではないかと思われます)

多くの場合、恐らくアプリトークンを利用して /debug_token を叩くことになると思います。アプリトークンは、Graph API経由で生成することもできますが、アプリIDとapp secretをそのままアプリトークンとして利用することもできるようです。その場合、2つをパイプで繋いだ以下のような文字列をトークンとして使います。

`app_id|app_secret`

参考: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

これで解決すればよいのですが...お試しください。